# Best practice to create and remove logged user class

Tags: ios, swift, logging

Could someone tell me the best way to create logging user class? Lets say i have something simple like this:

```
class User{

var username: String?
var email: String!
var years: Int!
var phone: Int?
}
```

now my app fetching data from server, so i want to fetch data when he will be logged correctly and then init User class with these vars. At the end i want to remove or deinitialize this user class because he's logged out. Can i make

```
static var logged: User?
```

`init` it somewhere after server'll return data and then assign to `nil` when logging out? Of course i want it to create new user when he will log again. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is an example of implementation, you have to user `UserDefaults` if you want to store data like that.

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard //global
```

and create singleton class like this

```
class User {

    private init() {}
    static let shared = User()

    public var name: String {
        get {
            return defaults.string(forKey: "name") ?? ""
        }
        set {
            defaults.set(newValue, forKey: "name")
            defaults.synchronize()
        }
    }
}
```

then you can do

```
User.shared.name = "SomeName"
let username = User.shared.name
```

when logout, just set every var to be `""` or nil, it is up to you.

Comment: thank you, i was looking for something like this. One more thing, is it safe to store it that way in user defaults?

Comment: @kam.voick for some properties like name/phone/token it is totally safe, data won't be lost until user deletes an app. it will be saved when updated too.